# Get ddmmss from difference between to datetime sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i want get difference between two date time with DAY HOUR MINUTE and SECOND

i write this query

```
select convert(time(0),('2015-12-12 16:51:08.490' - GETDATE())) as TimeDifference
```

but is get HOUR MINUTE and MILLISECOND like this `22:43:46` i want add day to the this format and get this out put

```
1:22:43:46
```

how can do it?

Comment: Well there are 24 hours in a day, and the rest is simple math.   Get the time difference in seconds, and do division to get minutes, hours and days.

Comment: did you try to use DATEDIFF to get the difference in seconds? So you can calculate the days, hours and so on from there and concat it to a string

Comment: @TabAlleman ,this query not good for my problem, can you give me sample query for get diffrence between 2 date DD,HH,MM,SS

Comment: @CPMunich can you give me sample query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
SELECT 
     CAST(DATEDIFF(ss, GETDATE(), '2015-12-12 16:51:08.490') / (60 * 60 * 24) AS VARCHAR(20)) + ':' +
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2015-12-12 16:51:08.490' - GETDATE(), 108)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your existing query as a starting point, you could simply do this:

```
select 
  CAST(DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), '2015-12-12 16:51:08.490') AS varchar(31))  --gets days
  + ':'
  + CAST(convert(time(0),('2015-12-12 16:51:08.490' - GETDATE())) AS varchar(31)) as TimeDifference
...
```